# Как уменьшить нагрузку на веб сервер

Tags: php

Имеется php скрипт который в цикле выполняет поиск записей по БД и запускается кроном каждую минуту.
Одна итерация цикла проходит примерно за 0.01-0.1 секунды, то есть за минуту запросов в БД будет намного больше чем нужно и создается лишняя нагрузка на процессор.
Необходимо выполнять запросы не более 10-30 раз в минуту, а не сотни-тысячи раз.
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли каким-то образом замедлить выполнение как то распределив нагрузку равномерно чтобы не было скачкообразных нагрузок?
Не знаю стоит ли использовать sleep в этом случае...

Comment: Не много не понятно, вы хотите ограничить число итераций в цикле? Вообще мне кажется лучше бы вам поменять логику работы вашего приложения, вот если бы вы на примере описали этот функционал, люди бы может быть подсказали метод решения оптимальней нежели мучить базу каждую минуту.

Comment: переписать логику так, чтобы исключить цикл и крон планировать с нужным интервалом? что у вас там в цикле этом происходит:

Comment: База постоянно пополняется, в этой базе нужно производить поиск нужных данных максимально часто, но не настолько чтобы сотни запросов в минуту были, достаточно пары десятков запросов в минуту. Необходимо сбалансировать нагрузку на сервер, т.е. чтобы запросы в БД не были скачкообразными а выполнялись например через определенный промежуток сбалансированно не сильно напрягая сервер

Comment: Полагаю в моем случае лучше всего использовать что-то вроде memcached

Comment: А для чего данные постоянно ищутся в БД, как используется результат этого поиска ? И да, вы могли бы сохранять данные не только в основную БД но и в мемкешед именно то, что потом ищется. И да, в цикле чтения БД в скрипте вполне можно расставлять sleep, что бы он ждал какое то время перед выполнением следующего запроса